# Should I leave splices when pulling new thermostat wire?

Tags: wiring, furnace, thermostat

My existing 4-wire thermostat cable comes out of the furnace, and each of the wires is wire-nutted to another wire. That then goes to the thermostat.

[image: splices]

I'm going to pull new cable to support a smart thermostat. Should I keep the splices, or should I run one continuous cable from the furnace all the way to the thermostat? If I should leave splices, should I put them all into a box?

The furnace was replaced a couple years ago, and I'm unsure if the splices were a result of that or a result of updated codes or best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is always best to have unspliced conductors. I would make sure to leave a small service loop (extra wire length) for other possible changes in the future.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct way to do it - UN-SPLICED. If you want it to work right all the time, no issues with possible breaks , resistive failures or mismatched colors end to end use a single run from unit to thermostat, you will be glad yo did.I placed a box in my wall where the thermostat comes in - so my wires are looped and restrained in the box. My thermostat mounts to the box.

Comment: @Ken I thought about putting a box in, but the ecobee3 apparently doesn't mount (nicely) to a box